# Using --dart-define with Xcode archive and distribute

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When building an appbundle for android I am able to use --dart-define with the `flutter build appbundle` shell command to define env variables for this bundle. How can I do that with Xcode workflow of Archive and Distribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the .ipa with this command `flutter build ipa --dart-define="var_name=value" --export-options-plist=ios/fastlane/ExportOptions.plist`

And the ExportOptions.plist is something like that

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>destination</key>
        <string>export</string>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>app-store</string>
        <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
        <dict>
                <key>your.app.id</key>
                <string>Provisioning Profile Name</string>
        </dict>
        <key>signingCertificate</key>
        <string>Apple Distribution</string>
        <key>signingStyle</key>
        <string>manual</string>
        <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
        <true/>
        <key>teamID</key>
        <string>YOU_TEAM_ID</string>
        <key>uploadSymbols</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I have to add that build ipa is only available in newer versions of Flutter, it is not available to all versions

Comment: you can also use the normal `flutter build ios`. To check whether the generated build is applied in xcode before archiving, you can open `ios/flutter/Generated.xcconfig` file and see `DART_DEFINES` line with your specified params there.

Comment: it's `ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig` with a capital F, in case anybody gets confused like me.

Comment: How to export this build to appstore then?
I build .ipa with flutter build ios, how to use it in archive?

Comment: I use fastlane, and it has a script for them.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/beta-deployment/#uploading-your-app